# How to programmatically add database fields to a Crystal Report in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to be able to programmatically add or remove database fields in my crystal report.
I am familiar with programmatically working to parameters but not with database fields, I just can figure out how to programmatically do what you do in the Database Expert.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports does not allow report designs to be modified at runtime.